# Python Image Library - Create and paste image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

How do I create a new image with a black background and paste another image on top of it?

What I am looking to do is turn some 128x128 transparent icons into 75x75 black background icons.

Doesnt work ...

```
import Image

theFile = "/home/xxxxxx/Pictures/xxxxxx_128.png"

img = Image.open(theFile)

newImage = Image.new(img.mode, img.size, "black")
newImage.paste(img)
newImage.resize((75,75))
newImage.save("out.png")

print "Done"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `resize` method returns a new image object, rather than changing the existing one.  Also, you should resize the image before pasting it.  The following works for me:

```
import Image

theFile = "foo.png"

img = Image.open(theFile)
resized = img.resize((75,75))
r, g, b, alpha = resized.split()

newImage = Image.new(resized.mode, resized.size, "black")
newImage.paste(resized, mask=alpha)
newImage.save("out.png")

print "Done"
```

I found an example of this `split` + `mask` technique from [this blog post](http://tobias.klpstn.com/2008/02/10/simple-image-masking-with-pil/).

Example input:

[image: Input image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: I get a resized image of the original PNG with transparency.

Comment: Sorry, I checked the results in a program that it seems uses a black background for transparent images anyway :)  I've updated my answer with a fixed version, tested properly this time.